# Imshow() size restrictions

Tags: c++, opencv

I have image 6750x6450 px and trying to display it with imshow() function from OpenCv.
When I display one image it's shown badly(some wired output), when I try to display two images get seqfault. Saving those images on hdd gives good results, images are saved, and they are correct, when I resize both they are also shown correctly. Has imshow() function some size restrictions?

code:

```
Mat bigImage1 = imread(...);
Mat bigImage2 = imread(...);
namedWindow("first",CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
namedWindow("second",CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
imshow("first",bigImage1);
imshow("second",bigImage2);
```

I'm working on desktop computer Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Hi, What I'm sure about is that OpenCV is not designed for big sizes images. What's your architecture? Desktop computer? 32/64 bits? Windows, Linux?
I found other examples of people using images larger than yours though : http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/42362

Comment: I've edited my question and provided my platform details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are probably larger than your current screen resolution. The problem seems to be that they are simply too big for OpenCV to handle them in a window.

To be certain, I would try your code on Mac or Linux since OpenCV is cross-platform and there are specific window management implementations for every OS.

Comment: For images this big, you need a visualizer other than imshow. Something along the line of Python Matplotlib imshow since it can do some resizing for visualization purpose. Or just save it as an image.